# Laravel .ENV accessibility?

Tags: laravel, apache, security, audit, logfile

I have had my SES key compromised because of Laravel accidentally being set to 'debug=true' which exposed the credentials, which has been fixed.  It was an oversight on my part, however, doing full digging I see access requests to .env in my apache log file, I don't understand how or why.  When I try to access the file I am unable.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
192.237.162.xx - - [17/Jul/2020:18:36:54 +0000] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 200 1288 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows 98)"
```

Comment: Automated bots will try various things like `.env` or `/../../../../etc/passwd` or things like that in an attempt to discover vulnerabilities. If you can't access the file by doing that request then most likely those bots won't either

Comment: I've witnessed that before but the status code of 200 alarmed me.  When I try to access the file with a GET request it returns a 404.  Unsure what they're doing to get the 200. @apokryfos

Comment: Maybe the redirection is in fact working and the 200 is being returned on the new page loaded?

Comment: Have you perhaps accidentally set up your server to serve the project's root somewhere? Like when you access the server via IP instead of domain?

Comment: That was it, the root was exposed on the IP on port 80.  Good lord.  Luckily the files were unaccesable and just the directories. @ceejayoz

Comment: Glad that pointed you in the right direction. Be sure to change every password or key in that file!

Comment: Oh my, on mobile I didn't even see the `200`. Dang!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by others, misconfigurations could lead to the `.env` file being exposed. Bots will search for it, but if you can't access it from the web, neither can they.

To prevent this ever from happening again, start configuring a blacklist in your `config/app` using the `debug_hide` key. This is a must for all Laravel projects described in the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/configuration#hiding-environment-variables-from-debug). It allows you to obfuscate values for given `.env` keys.

If your environment gets exposed, you absolutely need to check if your database is accessible other than localhost, if so, you have to change your password and any other sensitive information like email settings.

If the **APP_KEY** gets exposed, you need to rotate it.

When changing the `APP_KEY`:

- you have to know if you are using Laravel's default encryption method. If you are encrypting data, you need a plan to decrypt this data with your old key and encrypt it with the new one.
- all sessions will expire as soon as you changed that key with `php artisan key:generate`.

If the encrypted data is not vital, as in terms of breaking functionality like logins, etc. Store your old app key somewhere (and make sure you don't lose it!) and regenerate a new key immediately. Then figure out a plan to convert your encrypted data with your new key.

A common misconception is that your passwords will be unusable after a key change, this is nonsense. Passwords are hashed, not encrypted.

Till today, I'm still shocked to see that the `debug_hide` key is still **not** present in the [current default config/app](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/app.php). In my opinion, it is vital to hide the `APP_KEY` in the default configuration.

Comment: Excellent tips, I'll do them now.  I have rekey'd everything but will again for safety reasons.  The database is local only without any access outside the internal network, I'll still reset that password as well.  It appears as they were able to view the .env and browse directories but the files themselves returned 500 errors, except for HEAD requests which I don't think gives them anything.

Comment: It happens to all of us, even once :D I'll update my answer on rotating the `APP_KEY` If it gets exposed.